# Yii2 Upload to BLOB datatype in mysql database not working

Tags: php, yii2

I got a problem when i want to upload my images/files using BLOB datatype.

i using MYSQL

This is my view

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'binaryfile')->fileInput() ?>

<button>Submit</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

This is my Model

```
public function rules(){
 return [
        [['binaryfile'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'pdf ,png, jpg'],
        [['fileName'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['fileType'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
    ];
}
```

my Controller

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->binaryfile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'binaryfile');
        $model->fileName = $model->binaryfile->name;
        $model->binaryfile = file_get_contents($model->binaryfile->tempName);
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['site/file-upload']);
        }
    }
```

and this is the error of my problem.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its already been fixed.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->uploadedFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'uploadedFile');
        $model->fileName = $model->uploadedFile->name;
        $model->binaryfile = file_get_contents($model->uploadedFile->tempName);
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['site/file-upload']);
        }
    }
```